# How to unwrap custom serialized objects from "content" key with Jackon & Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I have customly serialized my object which is represented by this class:

```
public class Product {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Unit defaultUnit;
    private Section section;
}
```

Serialization:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Product product, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id", product.getId());
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", product.getName());
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("defaultUnit", product.getDefaultUnit().toString());
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("section", product.getSection());
}
```

However this produces an error which as I understand means that the default serializer has created a key and I have to provide it with a value:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Can not write a field name, expecting a value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value]
```

Now it is obvious that the solution is to wrap the fields adding

```
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
```

This however results in generating entity wrapped in "content" object:

```
"content": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Product",
  "defaultUnit": "Unit",
  "section": {
    "name": "Section"
  }
}
```

My question is whether it is possible to write the entity unwrapped that is without the "content" key.

The following is all the code associated with Product:
Product.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = ProductDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = ProductSerializer.class)
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @NonNull
    private Unit defaultUnit;

    @ManyToOne
    @NonNull
    private Section section;
}
```

ProductExcerpt.java

```
@Projection(name = "productExcerpt", types = {Product.class})
public interface ProductExcerpt {
    String getName();
    @Value("#{target.defaultUnit.toString()}")
    String getDefaultUnit();
    SectionExcerpt getSection();
}
```

ProductRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = ProductExcerpt.class)
@CrossOrigin
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

ProductSerializer.java

```
public class ProductSerializer extends StdSerializer<Product> {

    ProductSerializer(){
        super(Product.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Product product, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id", product.getId());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", product.getName());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("defaultUnit", product.getDefaultUnit().toString());
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("section", product.getSection());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

There is also ProductDeserializer class however I think that it is irrevelant in this case. I do not have a Controller configured beacause as far as I am concerned there is no need while using spring-data-rest.

Comment: It is not related with custom serialiser. Probably you serialise a wrapper object instead of `Product` object directly. Could you show how do you serialise objects?

Comment: There is hardly more to discover. The `serialize` method is in `ProductSerializer` class which extends `StdSerializer<Product>` thus I am pretty sure that is a product serializer class (If I am wrong please correct me). It also goes with `@JsonSerialize` annotation in `Product` class. Apart from that there is only `ProductReposiroty` repository but since there is no custom login in there I guess it does not affect the described problem.

Comment: Can you show  us the controller ,service , repository code related to your problem ?

Comment: I posted all the code related to Product. There is no controller because as far as I am concerned there is no need to define one while using sprind-data-rest

Comment: I tried without spring-data-jpa, directly serializing using ObjectMapper. `Product` serialzed just fine - unwrapped without 'content'. Is there any other configuration you think you didn't mention in the question? Try searching the project with keyword 'content'.

Comment: @Smile I searched the entire project and I didn't find anything. It seems that the content key is provided behind the scenes by the ObjectMapper. It generates the content keyword and then expects me to provide value/object. Can You share the code that runs corretly?

Comment: I manually created product object and serialized it with `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(product)`

Comment: It works the same way for me while calling the object mapper manually. So I guess the solution is to create a custom REST controller and implement mapping there?